# Activiti`s RuntimeServiceImpl::startProcessInstanceByKey cannot work well in a concurrent environment

Tags: java, workflow, activiti, bpmn

I've got a very strange question in `RuntimeServiceImpl::startProcessInstanceByKey`.

The code is like this:

```java
@Override
public String startProcessInstanceByKey(String processDefinitionKey, String businessKey,
    String authenticatedUserId, Map < String, Object > variables) throws RiskManageException {
    log.info("startProcessInstanceByKey,收到开启工作流 processDefinitionKey:{} ,businessKey:{},authenticatedUserId:{},variables:{}", //This can be printed normally
        processDefinitionKey, businessKey, authenticatedUserId, JSON.toJSON(variables));

    try {
        Assert.notNull(authenticatedUserId, "userCode 不能为空");

        Assert.notNull(processDefinitionKey, "流程定义key 不能为空");

        processCoreService.getIdentityService().setAuthenticatedUserId(authenticatedUserId);

        return processCoreService.getRuntimeService()
            .startProcessInstanceByKey(processDefinitionKey, businessKey, variables).getProcessInstanceId(); //This statement didn`t execute
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RiskManageException(ExceptionCodeEnum.START_PROCESS_ERROR, e); //Here throws an exception but the caller didn`t catch any
    }
}
```

The process instance couldn't be created sometimes in a concurrent environment without any exception. It often happens when JDBC connections are about to use up. I want to know more detailed information, what should I do?

Comment: If you get the exception, please give the details of the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but the problem is Activiti didn`t throw any exception , so it`s hard to locate what the problem is.